# can't get osd lyrics ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ppa

I tried to add ppa on my 14.04, but I got this error

```
Fetched 609 kB in 3min 44s (2,711 B/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/osd-lyrics/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/osd-lyrics/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I already try screenlets sth: like that but it doeesn't work either... please help me! guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I got it installed.  I downloaded it from [here](https://code.google.com/p/osd-lyrics/).  Once downloaded I used Gdebi to install it.  If you don't have Gdebi installed, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

Once installed, just open the file with it, and click install.  See images below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thx,finally i can successfully install osdlyrics on my 14.04

Comment: GDebi is no longer needed. The Software Centre handles individual package files just fine.

Comment: Using the deb in the link worked for me using Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that on http://ppa.launchpad.net/osd-lyrics/ppa/ubuntu/dists/ there is no trusty existed. That means the owner doesn`t update the OSD for trusty. but you can edot the sourselist to change "trusty" to quantal which is the newest version that OSD supported.